# How to split multiple UPPERCASE/delimiter/text using regex? (VBA)

Tags: regex, vba, split, uppercase

I've got 2k+ records with string followyng rule (LOCATION I UPPERCASE - text) x several times, like this:

```
I- TRZON - Fragmenty błony śluzowej trzonu żołądka w stanie przewleklego 
powierzchownego (++) aktywnego (++) zapalenia. W barwieniu Warthin-Starry 
nie stwierdza się bakterii odpowiadających Helicobacter pylori. II-ANTRUM + 
KĄT - Fragmenty błony śluzowej części odźwiernikowej żołądka w stanie 
przewlekłego głębokiego zapalenia (+++). W barwieniu Warthin-Starry nie 
stwierdza się bakterii odpowiadajacych Helicobacter pylori.
```

Which I'm trying to split as follows using regex:

```
Location - I- TRZON
Text Fragmenty błony śluzowej trzonu żołądka w stanie przewleklego powierzchownego (++) aktywnego (++) zapalenia. W barwieniu Warthin-Starry nie stwierdza się bakterii odpowiadających Helicobacter pylori.
Location II- ANTRUM + KĄT
Text Fragmenty błony śluzowej części odźwiernikowej żołądka w stanie przewlekłego głębokiego zapalenia (+++). W barwieniu Warthin-Starry nie stwierdza się bakterii odpowiadajacych Helicobacter pylori.
```

So far I managed to do this by creating something like this

```
([A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ\s,+\-0-9]*)[\s]?-+?(.*[^A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ\s,+\-0-9]) ([A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ\s,+\-0-9]+)*[\s]?-+?(.*)
```

But obviously it cannot manage those strings, where one or three pairs of location and text are possible. The main problems I encountered are hyphens used in text (see - Warthin-Starry).

If I try something more elegant, like

```
([A-ZŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓ]+[\s-\+,]*?)-(.*)
```

It obviously matches only the word before the first hyphen into the first group, and everything else into next.

To sum up: how to translate into regex something like: match, splitting into two groups: 1) UPPERCASE text with any other signs (no lowercase), followed by 2) text, that is as long as you encounter another UPPERCASE text.

I must admit that I'm fairly new to regex, but I searched for a few days and nothing seems to work universally (and it's only the beginning of extracting data from this string...)

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/u1XdKN/1)? `([A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ]+-[A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ\s,+-0-9]*?)\s*-\s*([^]*?)(?=[A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ]+-|$)`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! While it works on the string I provided, It didn't work at all in vba (?), and when I tried different string in regexr, it didn't match at all... I tested: TRZON, ANTRUM - In excisionibus examinatis: Gastritis chronica gradus minoris. W barwieniu Warthin-Starry nie stwierdza się bakterii odpowiadających Helicobater pylori.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure how you can do this with RegEx, i have a hard time myself to get my head around that syntax.

However, I would probably just use the DATA/Text To Columns, split with hyphen, and just concatenate back together the extra splits caused by hyphens in text.

If is not just an one off processing, you can always use VBA as well, something like:

```
Sub TextToColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim lRow As Long, sndHyphen As Long, R As Long

    lRow = ws.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    For R = 1 To lRow                                                               'Iterate through all rows containing this data
        sndHyphen = InStr(InStr(ws.Cells(R, 1), "-") + 1, ws.Cells(R, 1), "-")      'Get the hyphens positions
        ws.Cells(R, 2) = Left(ws.Cells(R, 1), sndHyphen - 2)                        'Get the data before the second hyphen
        ws.Cells(R, 3) = Mid(ws.Cells(R, 1), sndHyphen + 2)                         'Get the data after the second hyphen
    Next R

End Sub
```

Comment: Manual concatenation would be possible, but a long process. Also I wanted to understand more regex, since I'm going to need to extract much more data from these strings later... :) I managed to do this using different sub, see my other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input. I finally managed to do this using two subs:

```
Sub locfinder()

Dim myregexp As RegExp
Set myregexp = New RegExp
Dim myMatches As Variant
Dim myMatch As Variant
Dim str As String
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim endrow As Integer
Sheets("dane").Activate
endrow = LastRow
Dim rozp1, rozp2 As String

For i = 1 To endrow
str = Sheets("Dane").Cells(i, 10).Value
myregexp.Global = True
myregexp.Pattern = "([A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ]+[\s,+\-0-9]*[A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ]*[\s,+\-0-9]*[A-ZŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ]*[\s,+\-0-9]*|Trzon|Antrum)\s?-"

If Not str = "" Then
Set myMatches = myregexp.Execute(str)
 j = 1
 For Each myMatch In myMatches
    If myMatch.Value <> "" Then
    Sheets("Dane").Cells(i, j + 10).Value = Trim(myMatch.SubMatches(0))
    j = j + 1
    End If
Next
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Then extracted diagnoses using

```
Sub rozpfinder()
Dim myregexp As RegExp
Set myregexp = New RegExp

Dim myMatches As Variant
Dim myMatch As Variant
Dim str As String
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim endrow As Integer
Sheets("dane").Activate
endrow = LastRow
Dim rozp, loc As Collection
Dim splitted() As String
Dim rozpoznanie, lokalizacja
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Dane")

For i = 1 To endrow
    str = ws.Cells(i, 10).Value
    Set loc = New Collection
    Set rozp = New Collection

    For j = 1 To 2
        If ws.Cells(i, 10 + j) <> "" Then
            loc.Add ws.Cells(i, 10 + j).Value
        End If
    Next j
    For Each lokalizacja In loc
        If lokalizacja <> "I" Then
        str = Replace(str, lokalizacja, "xxx")
        Else
        lokalizacja = "I-"
        str = Replace(str, lokalizacja, "xxx-")
        End If
    Next lokalizacja
    splitted = split(str, "xxx")
    For j = 0 To UBound(splitted)
        If splitted(j) <> "" Then
        myregexp.Pattern = "-[^\w]"
        myMatch = myregexp.Replace(splitted(j), "")
        rozp.Add (Trim(myMatch))
        End If
    Next j
    j = 1
    For Each rozpoznanie In rozp
        ws.Cells(i, 12 + j).Value = rozpoznanie
        j = j + 1
    Next rozpoznanie
Next i
End Sub
```

While it wasn't 100% accurate, the number of records I need to correct is about 1%, so I guess it works :)